# Tablesorter partly works with IE8 but doesn't sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, tablesorter

Works with FF28 but not IE8, and I don't get any error messages. I'm using tablesorter 2.15.14 and jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
        <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("table").tablesorter( {sortList: [[1,1]]} ); 
        });     
        </script>     
    </head>
```

Only thing that works in IE8 is the CSS, when I click on header to make it Ascending and Descending, the color of the header changes, but the table stays the same and does not sort.

```
    th.tablesorter-headerDesc { 
    background-color: #3399FF; 
    } 

    th.tablesorter-headerAsc { 
    background-color: #FF8080; 
    }
```

One of the tables I'm using (table is populated from .csv file using js)

```
<div id="origtable">

            <table border="1" id="table_side" class="tablesorter">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Origin <br> Country</th>

                      <th>Count</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>    
          </div>
```

I've looked at the documentation and tried several methods, they all work with FF but still nothing with IE8.

EDIT 1:

jquery function that im using to populate html table, this is ofcourse after reading from .csv

```
function populateTableCounts(rowkey, tablename, hashdata)
    {
        var rowhtml = "";
        $.each(hashdata, function (key, value) {
             key = key.replace(/-/g, ' / ');
             key = key.replace(/:/g, ' , ');

             var rowdata=countrow.replace('$row_key', key);
             rowdata=rowdata.replace('$row_val', value);

            //add row <tr> to var rowhtml   
            rowhtml += rowdata;          
        });

        //append populated rowhtml to TBODY
        $('#' + tablename + ' tbody').append(rowhtml);
    }
```

EDIT 2:

Now I'm using tablesorter like this, but tables are not being updated on page load on IE8 cuz like Mottie said, intilization needs to be after files are loaded.. but I don't know how to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
       sortList: [[1,1]]
    });
    $("table").trigger("update"); 
    $("table").click(function(){ $("table").trigger("update"); });
});
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @Starscream1984 I'm using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2

Comment: The initialization of tablesorter should occur after the table is built from the csv file. Can you share that code?

Comment: @Mottie I updated the question with 2 edits. I can see what my problem is right now, tablesorter is being used before .csv data populates table. With firefox it's no problem, but with IE8 it is. So how can I wait sometime (like half a second until table is populated) before I use tablesorter?

Comment: Bind to the [`updateComplete` event](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updatecomplete).